# LISTAGG in Oracle gives NULL

Tags: sql, database, oracle12c, listagg

If a column value if too long, then listagg gives NULL output in Oracle 12c. What is the cause of this and what is the solution?

```
SQL> select length(algo_desc) from r2_temp where DECL = '305';
     32759
```

ALGO_DESC is very long, like 1045,2339,2389.......37364,58922,2389392
Now if I use LISTAGG then it gives NULL as follows:

```
SQL> select dump(listagg(algo_desc, ',') within group (order by algo_desc)) as algo_desc from r2_temp where DECL = '305';
     NULL
```

max size of column ALGO_DESC is 32767, it's extended varchar2 in 12c

Comment: `listagg()` is limited to the length of a `varchar2()`/`nvarchar2()`, which is more like 4000 characters.

Comment: I'm using extended varchar2 size i.e., VARCHAR2(32767)

Comment: Interesting. With some long values it seems to be corrupted, with dump showing lots of zeros (which looks like bug 19461687, but that's supposed to be fixed). And then at some point that corruption manifests as an overall null? Time to raise a service request, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);
-- or     CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF NUMBER;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JoinTable(TAB IN VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE, Joiner IN VARCHAR2) RETURN CLOB IS
    res CLOB;
BEGIN
    IF TAB IS NULL THEN 
        RETURN NULL; 
    END IF;
    IF TAB.COUNT = 0 THEN 
        RETURN NULL; 
    END IF;

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(res, FALSE, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
    IF TAB(TAB.FIRST) IS NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_LOB.APPEND(res, TAB(TAB.FIRST));
    END IF;
    IF TAB.COUNT > 1 THEN
        FOR i IN TAB.FIRST+1..TAB.LAST LOOP
            DBMS_LOB.APPEND(res, Joiner||TAB(i));
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
    RETURN res;

END JoinTable;



select JoinTable(CAST(COLLECT(algo_desc order by algo_desc) AS VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE), ',') as algo_desc 
from r2_temp 
where DECL = '305';
```

Comment: Thank's for your input. But this also doesn't work, gives NULL in the output.